# How can I get headers when using XDomainRequest

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm trying to execute a request using XDomainRequest on ie9, the problem I'm facing is when trying to get the response headers.

Does it support the getResponseHeader method or has a similar method in the object API?

Comment: If my answer provides helpful information for the issue then I suggest you, please accept it as an answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check the documentation and found that **XDomainRequest** does not have getResponseHeader method or a similar method.

In the documentation, I noticed that it is an obsolete and non-standard feature.

> **Obsolete**
>
> This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some
> browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any
> time. Try to avoid using it.
>
> **Non-standard**
>
> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not
> use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every
> user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
> implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Reference: [XDomainRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XDomainRequest)

Internet Explorer 9 is also out of support scope of Microsoft.

It is recommended to move to the latest Microsoft browsers or at least move to the IE 11 browser. Then after you can try to use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Hi Deepak-MSFT, yes the problem with the project I'm working on is we must support IE9 event Microsoft already finished the support for it. So I had to change the behavior on IE9.